# Converting a string "10.214.239" to integer

Tags: c

I have some strings of the format "10.214.239" that I want to convert to an integer. Some of the strings are only thousands, and thus only contain 1 dot, but some are millions, and thus contain 2 dots. Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: Remove all dots and cast to an integer?

Comment: Remove all dots and then use the [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function.

Comment: I could probably use a bit of an explanation of how to do that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int  i, len;
int result=0;

len = strlen(num);

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9' )
        result=(result*10)+(num[i]-'0')
}

printf("%d", result);
```

Comment: Better to make it long.

Comment: quickly written code to just should an idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

You roughly need this:

```
int main()
{
  const char num[] = "12.345.66";
  char buffer[100];

  // copy string to buffer skipping dots
  char c;
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; c = num[i]; i++)
  {
    if (c != '.')
      buffer[j++] = c;
  }

  // put the NUL strig terminator
  buffer[j] = 0;

  // convert string stripped of dots to long
  long number = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);

}
```

Disclaimer: this is non error checking, quickly written code that shouldn't be used as it stands here, but it just should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Not a very elegant solution, IMHO.

Comment: This solution does have the virtue of handling possible negative input values. The other solutions do not.

Comment: To be honest, this approach is much better in the long run. `strtol()` allows very thorough error checking.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
int i,ans=0;
for(i=0;num[i];i++) 
   if(num[i]!='.') ans=ans*10+num[i]-'0';

printf("%d",ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through each character, and use [`isdigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) from `<ctype.h>`to determine if characters are numbers. Something like this would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *test = "10.214.239";
    const char neg = '-';
    long number = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; test[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit(test[i])) {
            number *= 10;
            number += test[i] - '0';
        }
    }

    /* if first character is a dash, make sure the converted number is negative */
    if (test[0] == neg) {
        number *= -1;
    }

    printf("number = %ld\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach from all the other answers so far would be utilise the standard library functions designed to handle manipulate/handle strings. For example, this could be done with `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *test = "10.214.239";
    int vals[3] = {0, 0, 0};

    const int n = sscanf(test, "%i.%i.%i", &vals[0], &vals[1], &vals[2]);
    const int exponent = n < sizeof(vals)/sizeof(int) ? 1: 1E3;
    long number = vals[0]*1E3*exponent + vals[1]*exponent + vals[2]);

    printf("%ld\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, alternatively, you could use `strtok` to split the string and `atol` to convert each substring to a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
  char *test = "10.214.239";
  char *tok = test;
  const int exponent = 1e3;
  long ans = 0;

  while ((tok = strtok(tok, ".")) != NULL) {
    ans = ans*exponent + atol(tok);
    tok = NULL;
  }

  printf("%ld\n", ans);
  return 0;
}
```